# What are these long hexadecimal HTTP requests?

Tags: http, webserver

I'm receiving long hexadecimal requests on my webserver, such as: `/f588069cda088c9a0fc25509fc4ed8418fe47a447683243395e649753d2d4b87cce9c4b3cc16cb5f44068e6da475dbffa9689b9ad237b5c941bb9ad2aa6759f7e4e39ba3012202cdce328f7eccc7efa48642eec1870e15c39924bc3c790ba04c`

I've tried to decode them using hexadecimal convertor tools, but can't seem to get any output that's meaningful. What are these 192-character length requests?

Comment: Well is hard to say what is exactly, could be some encryption on the URI, could be some binary code, some protocol embedded on the URI and so on. My suggestions is to see if you see patterns on the other requests that are show in common with all of them

Comment: It's likely just random internet noise, probably nothing to worry  about.

Comment: Author here, accidentally made a new account instead of connecting my SE account. Here's another one. `acc0cdd7d0c9cac037ca240b174bd27f032dd9240021c008a4c1bf45f2105ada4f69a3172bed515fd05fd59af72ef47156d56b5056eccc99a19cc19e1f5b355be239a2ebceeff76cfd2566570a370a668402740638457b98025f0c1c81e59628`

Comment: All 192 characters, in between other clear potentially vulnerable endpoints, such as `/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php` and `/api/jsonws/invoke`

Answer (score 0):

The [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of this data indicates it is unlikely to be encrypted or compressed. An analysis can be found [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Entropy(%27Shannon%20scale%27)&input=ZjU4ODA2OWNkYTA4OGM5YTBmYzI1NTA5ZmM0ZWQ4NDE4ZmU0N2E0NDc2ODMyNDMzOTVlNjQ5NzUzZDJkNGI4N2NjZTljNGIzY2MxNmNiNWY0NDA2OGU2ZGE0NzVkYmZmYTk2ODliOWFkMjM3YjVjOTQxYmI5YWQyYWE2NzU5ZjdlNGUzOWJhMzAxMjIwMmNkY2UzMjhmN2VjY2M3ZWZhNDg2NDJlZWMxODcwZTE1YzM5OTI0YmMzYzc5MGJhMDRj). The Shannon entropy is 3.94, which is actually in the range of typical English text (usually between 3.5 and 5).

Converting the hexadecimal text to UTF-8, I got the following: `õ...Ú....ÂU üNØA.äzDv.$3.æIu=-K.ÌéÄ³Ì.Ë_D..m¤uÛÿ©h..Ò7µÉA».ÒªgY÷äã.£.".ÍÎ2.~ÌÇï¤.BîÁ...Ã.$¼<y. L`
I don't know what this means, but it *really* looks like a line from a packet capture, as you might see when running tcpdump or similar. I have no idea why your server would be getting sent these.

As far as determining whether you should be concerned, it is possible this is some kind of command and control protocol being used to communicate via your server. Perhaps you can try appending many of these requests together to see if you'll get more meaning when converting the totality of data to UTF. I'd also monitor your outbound network traffic, especially to the source IP behind these requests.

My best guess is this is just noise. Since you're curious however, these are some next steps you can take. Please update if you learn more!

Comment: Why do you think it's a packet capture? Pasting it into a packet decoder doesn't really show much.

Comment: I'm not sure honestly, it's more an intuition. Some questions which might help: how many of these requests have you gotten? What's the rate at which these are received? When did these start and did it coincide with system changes?

Comment: I think these are some sort of vulerable route scans. I received them as essentially one-off attempts, from different IPs, alongside the other routes in the comments of the question. One or two of the attempts would be these strange 192-character hexadecimal paths, that'd be logged as 404s